# infix to postfix runtime error in c

Tags: c, data-structures, postfix-notation

This is the code i have written to convert an infix expression to postfix expression without using structures in c language.But sometimes its giving unexpected output and sometimes its displaying "segmentation fault" error.whats the error in this code?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define size 50
int top=-1;
char s[size];
void push(char ch){
    s[++top] = ch;
}
char pop(){
    char ch = s[top--];return ch;
}
int pr(char elem)
    {                 
        switch(elem)
        {
        case '#': return 0;
        case '(': return 1;
        case '+':
        case '-': return 2;
        case '*':
        case '/': return 3;
        case '^':
        case '$': return 4;
        }
    }

int main(){

    char in[50],post[50],ch,br;
    int i=0,p=0;
    printf("\n\nenter the Infix Expression : ");
        scanf("%s",in);
    push('#');
    while(in[i++] != '\0'){
        ch=in[i];

        if((ch>=48 && ch<=57) || (ch>=65 && ch<=90) || (ch>=97 && ch<=122))
            post[p++] = ch;
        else if(ch == '(')
            push(ch);
        else if(ch == ')'){
            while(s[top] != '(')
                post[p++]=pop();
            br = pop();
        }
        else if(ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '*' || ch == '/' || ch == '^' || ch == '$'){
            while(pr(s[top]) >= pr(ch))
                post[p++] = pop();                  

            push(ch);      //if priority is less,only push will occur
        }

        //i++;
    }
    while( s[top] != '#')
        post[p++]=pop();
    post[p] = '\0';
    printf("\ninfix : %s \n postfix : %s\n",in,post);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Check that none of your indexes is out of range. For example with this input: `(2+4)*5`, in `while (s[top] != '(')`, `top` becomes negative. Great time to learn how to use your debugger now.

Comment: Also avoid "magic" numbers, write `'0'` instead of `48` etc.

Comment: It would help if you include what inputs cause problems!I think @Jabberwocky nailed it though. 
You could quickly fix the negative top index this by making `s` a circular buffer -- ie, try changing push to `s[(++top)%size] = ch;` and pop to `char ch = s[(top--)%size];`.

Comment: @GandhiGandhi not sure if that would help, I rather suspect a logic error.

Comment: Your function `pr` contains a `switch` statement without a default case. This means that the function may return an undefined value if it is passed any character other than those listed.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't look at the first character?

Comment: jabberwocky,sir even if top becomes -1,it will not b a problem.And u were right there was a logic error

Comment: Tim Randall,no it was an error in my code.that wasn't intentionally

Answer (score 0):

This is the debugged code.There was error in while condition .I was updating it and then storing it in ch

```
#include<stdio.h>
#define size 50
int top=-1;
char s[size];
void push(char ch){
    s[++top] = ch;
}
char pop(){
    char ch = s[top--];return ch;
}
int pr(char br)
    {                 
        switch(br)
        {
        case '#': return 0;
        case '(': return 1;
        case '+':
        case '-': return 2;
        case '*':
        case '/': return 3;
        case '^':
        case '$': return 4;
        }
    }

void main(){

    char in[50],post[50],ch,br;
    int i=0,p=0;
    printf("\n\nenter the Infix Expression : ");
        scanf("%s",in);
    push('#');
    while( (ch=in[i++]) != '\0'){
        if((ch>=48 && ch<=57) || (ch>=65 && ch<=90) || (ch>=97 && ch<=122))
            post[p++] = ch;
        else if(ch == '(')
            push(ch);

        else if(ch == ')'){
            while(s[top] != '(')
                post[p++]=pop();
            br = pop();
        }
        else if(ch == '+' || ch == '-' || ch == '*' || ch == '/' || ch == '^' || ch == '$'){
            while( pr(s[top]) >= pr(ch) )
          post[p++]=pop();
            push(ch);    //if priority is less,only push will occur
        }

        //i++;
    }
    while( s[top] != '#')
        post[p++]=pop();
    post[p] = '\0';
    printf("\ninfix : %s \n postfix : %s\n",in,post);

}
```